# Using a 2-D double array with std::cin gives weird SEGFAULT

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, gcc4.7

The question title may seem odd but this seems to be a strange bug in my code that I can't quite figure out.

```
      1 #include "linkern.h"
      2 #include "linkern-inl.h"
      4 #include <iostream>
      5 #include "tsp.h" //contains macro MAX_CITIES
      6 
      7 extern bool euclidean;
      8 extern double dist[MAX_CITIES][MAX_CITIES];
      9 
     10 void LinKernighan::inputData()
     11 {
     12     char buf[20];
     13     int no_cities;
     14     double coords[MAX_CITIES][2];
     15     double distance[MAX_CITIES][MAX_CITIES]; //works fine if this is commented out
     16     std::cin.getline(buf, 20);
     17     if (buf[0] == 'e') // if euclidean TSP
     18         euclidean = true;
     19     else
     20         euclidean = false;
     21     std::cin>>no_cities;
     22     Tour::NUM_CITIES = no_cities;
     23     nearest_neighbours.reserve(Tour::NUM_CITIES);
     24     for (int i=0; i<Tour::NUM_CITIES; i++)
     25         std::cin>>coords[i][0]>>coords[i][1];
     26     for (int i=0; i<Tour::NUM_CITIES; i++)
     27     {
     28         for (int j = 0; j < Tour::NUM_CITIES; ++j)
     29         {
     30             std::cin>>distance[i][j]; //works fine if this is commented out
     31             //dist[i][j] = round(dist[i][j]);
     32         }
     33     }
     34 }
```

The declaration of the 2-D double array causes me to get the following error when executing the next `std::cin.getline()` statement in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040245e in widen (__c=10 '\n', this=0x7ffff7dd7d60) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_facets.h:871
871     this->_M_widen_init();
```

It seems to work fine if I use only the `extern dist` variable. Also it works perfectly if I keep the declaration of `distance` but do not use it in line number 30. Of course this is only a code snippet of my larger tsp.cc file. If anyone requires any more info, I'd be glad to provide it. I just hope I haven't missed something obvious in my sleep-deprived state. :)

I'm using gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)

Comment: At the line `std::cin >> distance[i][j];` does it run through that correctly for a while and then eventually crash or does it crash on the first loop

Comment: Actually it crashes on encountering the line std::cin.getline(buf, 20) itself without ever getting to the loop. I think the answer given by peterept seems to hold water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double distance[MAX_CITIES][MAX_CITIES]` array is being allocated on the stack, and is causing your program to crash when something access the memory in the function.

This doesn't happen for the one outside the function because the compiler/linker allocates that block in the heap.

The solution is to dynamically allocate the memory (easiest is a single block):

```
double *distance = new double[MAX_CITIES*MAX_CITIES];

some_value = distance[(i*MAX_CITIES)+j];

delete[] distance;
```

Of course, this could still fail if MAX_CITIES is large, so then handle the failure gracefully.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I am exceeding my stack limit? That seems to be a valid explanation. Thanx a ton. Just for the sake of argument is there some way I can change the amount of stack space available for my functions?

Comment: I tested my code after increasing my stack space limit by using ulimit -s and the code works fine.